# Why "Sonar Way with find bugs" has no PMD rule repository?

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

I have setup SonarQube Ver 4.3.3 , but when i navigate to Quality Profile -> Sonar Way with find bugs -> Coding Rules -> Repository i do not see any PMD rule repository.

I can only see Common Sonar, FindBugs and Sonar Qube rule repositories.
Does it means that my SONAR is not is not checking PMD rules ?

Answer (score 7):

You do not see any PMD rule repository because the java plugin reimplemented the PMD rules (not a 1 on 1 match).
For more details, please read [this](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-java-analyzer-the-only-rule-engine-you-need/).

Please note the sonar-pmd-plugin is still supported. I advice to install a more recent version of the java plugin.

If you specifically want to see the PMD rules, please install the PMD plugin

Comment: But when i select "Common SonarQube" as repository and do a search by keeping all other filters as "Any" i just see these 5 rules : Duplicated blocks (active), Insufficient branch coverage by unit tests ( active ), 
Failed unit tests, 
Insufficient comment density, 
Insufficient line coverage by unit tests, 
Skipped unit tests

Comment: Which version of the java plugin do you have ?

Comment: java version  2.1. Do I need to also install the sonar PMD plugin seperately ?

Comment: if you want to see specifically the PMD rules, yes. Note equivalent exists in the java plugin

Comment: ok, so the PMD checking is handled by the java plugin and i do not necessarily need to install an additional PMD plugin.

Comment: I installed the the plugin and was able to see the PMD repository. So the only thing that i need to confirm is that the Java plugin covers PMD rules.

Comment: @Ash PMD rules are covered by PMD plugin. 
Java plugin provides its own analyzer made with love and passion at SonarSource and we (SonarSource team) recommend to use this analyzer rather than PMD because we tend to think it is better on many points.

Comment: @benzonico, thanks a lot for clearing my doubts. i have one question, how do i know what all PMD rules are covered by the Java Plugin that i am using. One way to do this is maually checking the rules one by one. I checked the release-note but could not find it. I have found the following  [link](http://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/pmd.html) which give some idea.

Comment: The link does not give you "some idea" it gives you the current state of the sonar-java rules compared to PMD rules.

Comment: @benzonico, is there any way of checking this comparison for all/previous versions of java-plugin ? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: no, there is not. We really really recommend you to use latest versions of plugins. 2.1 of java is really growing old and there was a looot of work done since then.